# Get the current inputed value parameter (PHP)

Tags: php

How can I get the current inputed value of my parameter in url?
for example this is my url

```
"**www.example.com/register?redirect=**"
```

when I input a value in the redirect parameter for example is

```
https://www.google.com
```

how can I get that value of redirect?

Comment: `$_GET['redirect']`

Comment: have you tried `$_GET["redirect"]`?

Comment: `echo $_GET["redirect"]` will print the value in URL.

Comment: yes I already try that but in my case my default redirect value is empty. then if I instert a value manually in url how to get the value of my redirect parameter? @BhavikShah

Comment: Let me ask you this first. Do you even know how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comments are correct, but I wanted to take a second to explain why and provide some useful links.

```
$redirect = (isset($_GET['redirect'])) ? $_GET['redirect'] : false
```

Through this superglobal, you can access any parameter included in the URL. The values passed to you through this are urlencoded. YOu can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

What we did in the code above is this: 
    - Check if the redirect param hasbeen filled (you could aso just use empty() below )
    - Assign the redirect value to our `$redirect` variable if it is set, otherwise assign it false.

Using that, you can redirect the user there if it's set:

```
if($redirect) {
  header("Location: ".$redirect);
}
```

---

The downvote above isn't mine, but this isn't such a great question. I understand that you are new to the network, and everyone has to start somewhere. Please try to make sure you include code samples and do a bit of research yourself prior to your next question on SO.